# How to set the parameter of a URL as the mail recipient in tibco BW?

Tags: html, email, tibco, businessworks

I have a Tibco BW process which has a Send Mail task. It sends the mail to multiple recipients. The body of the mail contains a link with a parameter. When any of the recipient clicks on that link, the recipient name must be sent as the parameter to that link. 
How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `concat()` function when building the email body.  This will allow you to construct the body from a combination of values which may be literal values of variables.

Comment: Exactly... Just use concat and include something like this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string. This will end up being an HTTP GET query on the target server.